# Generic class using generic parameter

Tags: java, generics

I want to achieve the following.

I have a generic class `Node<K,T,V>` which looks as follows:

```
public class Node<K,T,V>{

/**
 * @return the key
 */
public K getKey() {
    return key;
}
/**
 * @param key the key to set
 */
public void setKey(K key) {
    this.key = key;
}
// etc...
```

Now I want to have a class `Tree` which operates on Nodes with arbitrary parametrized types:

```
public class Tree <Node<K,V,T>> {
   public void insert(Node<K,V,T> node){
      K key = node.getKey();
      // do something...
   }
// ... etc...
}
```

This, however, does not work, since Eclipse tells me the line `public class Tree <Node<K,V,T>>` does not look good :) If I change it to

```
public class Tree <Node> {
```

It tells me that the type Node is hiding the type Node. How can I achieve that from the Tree class I can properly access the types K, V and T?

I'm pretty sure this question has been answered a bazillion times. I did, however, not find anything at all - so sorry for that!!!

Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't apologize for a good question ;-)

Comment: Thank you @ChristianSt.! And @Shail016, thank you for the solution. I went for the second solution. It does not read as nicely as my initial try, but it works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can change your tree to :

```
class Tree<K, T, V> {
    public void insert(Node<K, T, V> node) {
        K key = node.getKey();
        // do something...
    }
    // ... etc...
}
```

or if you want to bind it to Node,

```
class Tree2<N extends Node<K, T, V>, K, T, V> {
    public void insert(N node) {
        K key = node.getKey();
        // do something...
    }
    // ... etc...
}
```

Comment: I was going to write the second one but was too slow, nicely done :) Although it'd be better to maintain the <K,V,T> parameter order.

Comment: thanks, edited the order for Node<K,T,V> as defined by the op